# how can we add a username field in registration form using Django oscar

Tags: django-oscar

I'm trying to add username field in registration form in django oscar. Please can any one help and tell me how to add this field in the form.

Comment: I found the code for the oscar's User model here (https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/customer/abstract_models.py#L75) , maybe you can override it and try to give username, the EmailUserCreate form is here (https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/customer/forms.py#L117), maybe forking and overriding them both could solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Adding a username is easier than you expect. You need to override the customer app of Django oscar by following command:

`python manage.py oscar_fork_app customer project_name`

After that create a form.py file in the newly customer module located in project_name folder. And append the following code onto the file:

```py
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from oscar.apps.customer.forms import EmailUserCreationForm as CoreEmailUserCreationForm
from oscar.core.compat import (existing_user_fields, get_user_model)

User = get_user_model()


class EmailUserCreationForm(CoreEmailUserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username',)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])

        if 'username' in [f.name for f in User._meta.fields]:
            user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Note: don't forgot to include your customer app in your **INSTALLED_APPS** in settings.py like this 'project_name.customer.apps.CustomerConfig'

[image]